# I Need To Help Me To Make ParseINT Work With (row.find)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuBJw.png)How To Use **ParseINT** With `row.find()` I Try This Code But It's Not Working

That My Code :

```
       function update_qty() {

var row2 = $(this).parents('.item-row');

var price2 =  row2.find(parseInt($('.qty').val())) + 

row2.find(parseInt($('.qty2').val())) ;

price2 = roundNumber(price2,2);
```

Comment: Stop using sentences like : **help me!** ,**Please help** ,**i need help** . in `stackoverflow` all questions  asked with the **help** goal . no need to say it

Comment: And then, please go read [ask] and [mcve]. “It’s not working” is not a proper problem description.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to find an element with the sum of the contents of .qty and .qty2. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/find/) of the .find() method, I believe you are looking for another method. What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to sum the two numbers in 'qty' and 'qty2' and output to 'last_qty'

Comment: so go for `$(".last_qty").html(parseInt($('.qty').val()) + row2.find(parseInt($('.qty2').val()))`

Comment: But it does not appear